# Autosize WinForm in Panel VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autosize

How to make the form A size follow the panel size in the form B when i maximize or normal size form B, because form A is displayed in the form panel B in vb.net. sorry for my bad english, hope the masters can help me. This my code in form Main :

```
Private Sub TVMenu_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TVMenu.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
        Select Case TVMenu.SelectedNode.Name
            Case Is = "nGuru"
                FmGuru.Close()
                FmGuru.TopLevel = False
                FmGuru.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
                FmGuru.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                PContent.Controls.Add(FmGuru)
                FmGuru.Show()
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

I mean FmGuru show in panel FormMain, when i show FmGuru when FormMain size Normal FmGuru show Normal, but when I maximize FmMain, FmGuru not follow to maximize. 
thank before

ilustration :

[Normal Form Size Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfSYG.jpg)

[Max Form Size Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMIiN.jpg)

Comment: You'd almost always set its Dock property to DockStyle.Fill since anything else makes little sense.  Show your code if that doesn't help.

Comment: You can use MDI forms for this. Otherwise dock the form in the panel.

Comment: Substitute `FmGuru.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized` with  `FmGuru.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`

Comment: thank's for Mr. Jimi, I tried it with the code, but it still doesn't follow the panel size.

Comment: What do you mean that the formGuru does not maximise also, when you Maximize the form, do you change the size of the panel as well?, because if you did not change the size of the panel when maximizing the form, there is no way the form in the panel's size will change.

Comment: thank for preciousbetine, the panel has been set by using dockstyle.fill

Comment: @preciousbetine  "if you did not change the size of the panel when maximizing the form, there is no way the form in the panel's size will change" Not true. If you set the panels Dock property to Fill the panel will change size along with its container.

Comment: @Mr. Jimi, it has been checked using color on the panel, and the panel follows the size of the main form, but the form that appears in the panel still does not follow the panel size.

Comment: @Mary OP did not state that the panel is docked to the form; so I assumed there were other controls in the form.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works without problems. You have something (an event hadler maybe, or some other setting not shown here) that compromises the process. Or, you are looking at the Controls inside the embedded Form. Those Controls, if not docked or anchored in some way, won't follow the parent size change and remain sized as normal.

Comment: Under the Form's resize event; set the Form Guru's size to that of the panel

Comment: My problem has been resolved, I forgot to set the autoscroll on the panel that was used, after being set to true, the form size can already follow the panel size, thanks to everyone for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TVMenu_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TVMenu.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
        Select Case TVMenu.SelectedNode.Name
            Case Is = "nGuru"
                FmGuru.Close()
                FmGuru.TopLevel = False
                FmGuru.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal 
                pContent.Autoscroll = True
                FmGuru.Dock = Dockstyle.Fill
                FmGuru.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
                FmGuru.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                PContent.Controls.Add(FmGuru)
                FmGuru.Show()
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```